# Google maps Verify two latlng are on or near to path in the correct direction

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-maps, gis

I'm trying to figure out a way to verify if two points (LatLng) are on a path (polyline) or near to it, with certain tolerance and in the right direction.

[image]

I expect to get a function that accepts an array of points, a polyline and the tolerance. Or a combination of services.

```
function isPointsOnPath(points, polyline, tolerance): boolean
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You can insert your polygon i.e. an area with your `polyline` with the extra tolerance and then use [`containsLocation`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/poly-containsLocation).
You need to fill the array of points that draw your desired polygon.
[Check this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sdqm6pud/)

Also you can use `isLocationOnEdge` from geometry library.

> isLocationOnEdge(point:LatLng, poly:Polygon|Polyline, tolerance?:number)
>   
>  Tolerance is based on the decimal place accuracy desired in terms of lat/long 
>   
> e.g (44.9875, 35.9812) is on the polyline, if the tolerance is `0.00001` then if you change the point to (44.9876, 35.9812) the point will be on the polyline.

An example of `containsLocation`:

[image: points within a polygon defined in array]

```js
function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: 24.886, lng: -70.269},
          zoom: 5,
        });

        var triangleCoords = [
          {lat: 25.774, lng: -80.19},
          {lat: 18.466, lng: -66.118},
          {lat: 32.321, lng: -64.757}
        ];

        var bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({paths: triangleCoords});

        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
          var resultColor =
              google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(e.latLng, bermudaTriangle) ?
              'blue' :
              'red';

          var resultPath =
              google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(e.latLng, bermudaTriangle) ?
              // A triangle.
              "m 0 -1 l 1 2 -2 0 z" :
              google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE;

          new google.maps.Marker({
            position: e.latLng,
            map: map,
            icon: {
              path: resultPath,
              fillColor: resultColor,
              fillOpacity: .2,
              strokeColor: 'white',
              strokeWeight: .5,
              scale: 10
            }
          });
        });
      }
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDztlrk_3CnzGHo7CFvLFqE_2bUKEq1JEU&libraries=geometry&callback=initMap"></script>
```

> [Example with `isLocationOnEdge` on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rujstx28/)

[image: isLocationOnEdge]

> Complete [source code](https://github.com/jefersondeoliveira/android-hackathon/blob/master/google-maps-utils/library/src/com/google/maps/android/PolyUtil.java) of `isLocationOnEdge` for server migration

Comment: Well, there is two things to verify mate, the closeness and the direction of the points compared to path direction.

Comment: I guess you have an array of points to generate your polyline. You can draw a rect with the upper and lower bound in this array and feed it to the triangleCoords function (in your case a polygonCoords)

Comment: forget to mention that I need to do it in Server-side.

Comment: I think isLocationOnEdge is the best fit, check updated answer

Comment: I was working on migrating this function to the Server side, but this function doesn't help on figuring the direction problem

Comment: Check the source, this might help for your migration

Comment: I already did that, mate. the function is on the server side thanks for your help. Still the direction problem, I can't find a straightforward way to solve it